# Convert Byte [] to image in silverlight

Tags: image, silverlight, arrays

i have a Silver light Application need to Bind Image in Datagrid , i have an image as a `byte[]`. i have approx 500+ data in `observablecollection<User>`how can i  Convert my data in to image , in asp.net we can user datarowbinding event but in silverlight how can we do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in traditional asp.net we have such types of event from that we can manage the row binding , in silverlight you can use ivalueconvertor for that.
bind your image with image propery data aslso define your convertor for convert byte[] to image

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <Myerp:ConvertByteArrayToImge x:Key="ConvertByteArrayToImge"></Myerp:ConvertByteArrayToImge>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

in your image

```
<Image x:Name="UploadedIcon" Grid.Column="0" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Icon,Converter={StaticResource ConvertByteArrayToImge}}" />
```

Converter Class

```
public class ConvertByteArrayToImge : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is byte[])
            {
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream((Byte[])value);
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BitmapImage empImage = new BitmapImage();
                if (memStream.Length > 0)
                    empImage.SetSource(memStream);
                return empImage;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```